# Compare 2 strings of type string and LPWSTR

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I'd like to compare a `string` for example `"Tedt2.csv"` to `&value` which is `LPWSTR` in the declaration of the function. This is my base code which works:

```
PWSTR   value = nullptr;
HRESULT hr    = properties->GetStringValue(key, &value);
```

I tested many approches like

```
if (wcsstr(&value, L"Tedt2.csv") == 0)
{
   wprintf(L"%ws: %ws\n", keyName, value);
}
```

but it always enters the `if`.

Can someone help me please? It should be trivial but I'm a bit lost with C++. I've to make a proof of concept.

Comment: does that even compile?

Comment: `wcsstr()` searches for a string within a string, it does not perform a string comparison.

Comment: @tenfour well it compiles yes, but it enters every time

Comment: most important, you should not use `&value` in the call to `wcsstr`, but just `value`.

Comment: why does it "not work"?

Comment: @default the compare wasn't effective. It entered always in the "if"

Comment: @P.Sohm I added that to your question so that others who read it sees that information immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`wcsstr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9da80kz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) searches for a string within a string, it does not perform a string comparison. It returns `NULL` if the rhs is not found in the lhs. The `0` in this context will be converted to a null pointer and the `if` branch will entered when `"Tedt2.csv"` is not found in `value`. Use [`wcscmp()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/e0z9k731%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead:

```
if (wcscmp(value,  L"Tedt2.csv") == 0)
{      //  ^ remove & also
}
```

Or use [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) that provides `operator==()`:

```
#include <string>

const std::wstring search_string(L"Tedt2.csv");
if (search_string == value)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

and without & ?

```
if (wcsstr(value, L"Tedt2.csv") == 0)

 ... make something when "Tedt2.csv" not appear in value
```

your `value` is a pointer. You are passing a pointer to a pointer, but you need a pointer

```
wchar_t *wcsstr(   wchar_t *str,   const wchar_t *strSearch ); // C++ only
```